# Why use getattr() instead of __dict__ when accessing Python object attributes?

Tags: python, introspection

In source examples and SO answers that have some degree of Python object introspection, a common pattern is:

```
getattr(some_object, attribute_name_string)
```

Is there a reason why this pattern is preferred to:

```
some_object.__dict__[attribute_name_string]
```

which seems to be more directly showing what's going on?  Is it because the latter is too close to a particular implementation in CPython that may be subject to change?

**NB** Original question incorrectly identified the popular idiom as:

```
some_object.__getattr__(attribute_name_string)
```

Comment: [To respect the descriptor protocol.](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Thank you, am reading the linked docs.

Comment: In a way, the reason for using `getattr` is *exactly* the reason you’ve identified as in support of `__dict__`: it shows directly what’s going on, and thus violates encapsulation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`some_object.__getattr__` is **not** a common pattern. `getattr(some_object, attribute_name_string)` is the proper way of accessing attributes dynamically.

Not all instances *have* a `__dict__` attribute; a class that uses `__slots__` for example won't have that attribute. Next, attributes are not necessarily found *on the instance*, but are class attributes instead. `getattr()` will find those, looking at `__dict__` will not find them. Attributes on the class may also depend on the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html).

There may be uses for direct access to the `__getattr__` hook or the `__dict__` attribute, but those are specialised uses only. `__getattr__` is only used if the attribute was not first found elsewhere, for example (so for attributes **not** present on the class or in `instance.__dict__`).

Comment: sorry, my bad - you're right, it was `getattr(obj, attr)` rather than `obj.__getattr__` that I keep seeing.  Thank you for the enlightening response.